# openlayers 3 ol.format.WFS writeTransaction produces incorrect XML for simple UPDATE transaction

Tags: openlayers-3

I have used the ol.format.WFS#writeTransaction method successfully to serialize the WFS-t XML for an **insert** operation to GeoServer, but when I attempt to do the same thing for an **update** operation the method produces an invalid WFS-t request.  Is it possible that I am initializing the ol.format.WFS object incorrectly?  Or maybe I am passing the wrong options to the writeTransaction method?  Or maybe it's a bug in OpenLayers3?

Here is the gist of my Javascript:

```
var wfst = new ol.format.WFS({
    featureNS: "mypoints",
    featureType: "test_points"
});
var options = {
    gmlOptions: {srsName: "EPSG:3857"}, 
    featureNS: "mypoints",
    featureType: "test_points"
};
var node = wfst.writeTransaction(null, [thePoint], null, options);
var shouldBeValidXML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node)
```

Here's an example of the XML that that produces:

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Update typeName="feature:test_points" xmlns:feature="mypoints">
    <Property>
      <Name>geometry</Name>
      <Value>
        <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857"><pos>-10606301.721251432 4226568.758428884</pos></Point>
      </Value>
    </Property>
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <FeatureId fid="test_points.fid--62e21e8_153971e1869_-7ffe"/>
    </Filter>
  </Update>
</Transaction>
```

The issue is in line 2, where it says:

```
<Update typeName="feature:test_points" xmlns:feature="mypoints">
```

That makes GeoServer throw a *NoApplicableCodeException*, which in turn is somehow related to a generic *java.lang.NullPointerException*.  **However**, when I replace that line with the following, the request works beautifully:

```
<Update typeName="mypoints:test_points">
```

My specific questions are as follows:

- Is `typeName="mypoints:test_points"` actually the correct way to form the request?
- If so, what am I doing wrong with ol.format.WFS to get this bad XML?  Where is `feature` coming from?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`featureNS: "mypoints"` is wrong, you should be using a URI instead

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the issue.